# Topology reference request

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I am looking for a short topology document,which is roughly 60-80 pages long and touches on 
metric spaces,open and closed sets,perfect,bounded sets,limit points,compact,perfect and connected sets.

Can anyone please point me to such a resource?I intend to use it primarily as preparation for study of real analysis. Figures and illustrations with proper proofs will be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Marsden's "Elementary classical analysis". The first 80 or so pages cover much of what you mentioned. Lots of exercises, focus on understanding.

I like the metric spaces section in Kolmogorov & Fomin's "Introductory Real Analysis".

Comment: Marsden's text seems fine.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Mendelson's [Introduction to Topology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486663523) is concise and serves well as preparation for a Real Analysis course. It's also very cheap. I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

*Topology*, by Munkres. Just read the relevant sections.

One of the most well-written math books IMO.

Answer (score 0):

My first introduction to topology came through Willard's General Topology.  It's a little more in depth than what you've asked for, but you can always just skim the relevant sections. It's a fantastic, highly readable account.  In addition, Rudin's PoMA section on topology covers the bare essentials of what you're looking for in the context of real analysis.

Comment: Rudin seems to make few concessions when it comes to infusing some intuition.I really want to avoid that book as my first introduction to topology.

Comment: I would violently agree with this.